# What is TBS when talking about databases?

Tags: sql, database

What does mean abbreviation "TBS" in Oracle database? .

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TaBleSpaces

Each table is stored in a segment.  Segments are stored in tablespaces.  Each segment is allocated in units of "extents" which are allocated in database "blocks".

tablespace -> segment -> extent -> block

You can explicity define tablespaces.  You can select which tablespace a table's segment is created in at CREATE TABLE time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[Oracle Concepts - Tablespaces](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/tablespaces_concepts.htm)

Answer (score 1):

TBS generally refers to `TableSpaces` in oracle.....